# How to design an algorithm to calculate countdown style maths number puzzle

Tags: algorithm, combinatorics

I have always wanted to do this but every time I start thinking about the problem it blows my mind because of its exponential nature.

The problem solver I want to be able to understand and code is for the countdown maths problem:

Given set of number X1 to X5 calculate how they can be combined using mathematical operations to make Y.
You can apply multiplication, division, addition and subtraction.

So how does `1,3,7,6,8,3` make `348`?

Answer: `(((8 * 7) + 3) -1) *6 = 348`.

How to write an algorithm that can solve this problem? Where do you begin when trying to solve a problem like this? What important considerations do you have to think about when designing such an algorithm?

Comment: Brute force? I.e. try all combinations until you have the correct answer.

Comment: +1 Really cool problem. The most difficult operator is the combination operation, where you place 2 or more digits next to each other creating a double-digit (or triple- etc) number, because that operator can only be used on "raw" numbers and not on computed numbers. Example: 368 - 17 - 3 = 348.

Comment: This answer seems relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14309515/all-possible-numerical-expressions/14309855#14309855

Comment: Brute force. And you can skip the rest as soon as any partial result is not an integer. (At least for the TV-show I know this is a restriction).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Very quick and dirty solution in Java:

```
public class JavaApplication1
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1, 3, 7, 6, 8, 3);
        for (Integer integer : list) {
            List<Integer> runList = new ArrayList<>(list);
            runList.remove(integer);
            Result result = getOperations(runList, integer, 348);
            if (result.success) {
                System.out.println(integer + result.output);
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    public static class Result
    {

        public String output;
        public boolean success;
    }

    public static Result getOperations(List<Integer> numbers, int midNumber, int target)
    {
        Result midResult = new Result();
        if (midNumber == target) {
            midResult.success = true;
            midResult.output = "";
            return midResult;
        }
        for (Integer number : numbers) {
            List<Integer> newList = new ArrayList<Integer>(numbers);
            newList.remove(number);
            if (newList.isEmpty()) {
                if (midNumber - number == target) {
                    midResult.success = true;
                    midResult.output = "-" + number;
                    return midResult;
                }
                if (midNumber + number == target) {
                    midResult.success = true;
                    midResult.output = "+" + number;
                    return midResult;
                }
                if (midNumber * number == target) {
                    midResult.success = true;
                    midResult.output = "*" + number;
                    return midResult;
                }
                if (midNumber / number == target) {
                    midResult.success = true;
                    midResult.output = "/" + number;
                    return midResult;
                }
                midResult.success = false;
                midResult.output = "f" + number;
                return midResult;
            } else {
                midResult = getOperations(newList, midNumber - number, target);
                if (midResult.success) {
                    midResult.output = "-" + number + midResult.output;
                    return midResult;
                }
                midResult = getOperations(newList, midNumber + number, target);
                if (midResult.success) {
                    midResult.output = "+" + number + midResult.output;
                    return midResult;
                }
                midResult = getOperations(newList, midNumber * number, target);
                if (midResult.success) {
                    midResult.output = "*" + number + midResult.output;
                    return midResult;
                }
                midResult = getOperations(newList, midNumber / number, target);
                if (midResult.success) {
                    midResult.output = "/" + number + midResult.output;
                    return midResult
                }
            }

        }
        return midResult;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

It's basically just simple brute force algorithm with exponential complexity. 
However you can gain some improvemens by leveraging some heuristic function which will help you to order sequence of numbers or(and) operations you will process in each level of `getOperatiosn()` function recursion.

Example of such heuristic function is for example difference between mid result and total target result.

This way however only best-case and average-case complexities get improved. Worst case complexity remains untouched.

Worst case complexity can be improved by some kind of branch cutting. I'm not sure if it's possible in this case.

Comment: That source code does not compile on my machine (javac 1.6.0_41).

Comment: Yes, there is Diamond notation - `List<Integer> runList = new ArrayList<>(list);` you have to use Java 7 or replace Diamond notation with classic java syntax.

Comment: I believe this solution is not exhaustive. For the original question it returns only 5 results, whereas my version returns 500. I'm not sure that it'd find a valid solution for each possible problem if it seemingly misses some valid matches.

Comment: I did some tests, and this indeed fails to find a match for `382 1,3,7,6,8,3`, for example. (a valid match is `382 = ((7 * ((3 + 8) * (6 - 1))) - 3)`)

Comment: I thought that there should be implicit parenthesis like described in example - `(((8 * 7) + 3) -1) *6 = 348` isn't it? Can you confirm that we can also make use of parenthesis? In that case I can extend my solution.

Answer (score 7):

Sure it's exponential but it's tiny so a good (enough) naive implementation would be a good start. I suggest you drop the usual infix notation with bracketing, and use postfix, it's easier to program.  You can always prettify the outputs as a separate stage.

Start by listing and evaluating all the (valid) sequences of numbers and operators.  For example (in postfix):

```
1 3 7 6 8 3 + + + + + -> 28
1 3 7 6 8 3 + + + + - -> 26
```

My Java is laughable, I don't come here to be laughed at so I'll leave coding this up to you.

To all the smart people reading this: yes, I know that for even a small problem like this there are smarter approaches which are likely to be faster, I'm just pointing OP towards an initial working solution.  Someone else can write the answer with the smarter solution(s).

So, to answer your questions:

- I begin with an algorithm that I think will lead me quickly to a working solution. In this case the obvious (to me) choice is exhaustive enumeration and testing of all possible calculations.
- If the obvious algorithm looks unappealing for performance reasons I'll start thinking more deeply about it, recalling other algorithms that I know about which are likely to deliver better performance.  I may start coding one of those first instead.
- If I stick with the exhaustive algorithm and find that the run-time is, in practice, too long, then I might go back to the previous step and code again.  But it has to be worth my while, there's a cost/benefit assessment to be made -- as long as my code can outperform Rachel Riley I'd be satisfied.
- Important considerations include my time *vs* computer time, mine costs a helluva lot more.

Comment: This is definitely the thing to do. The order of the problem is 4^5 operator combinations * (9 choose 4) places for operators. (The first element in the string must be a number and the last must be an operator). Other sequences may produce illegal trees. That's just about 100M combinations ?

Comment: Also the selection of the representation of the equation is correct -- postfix or reverse polish can represent all combinations of parenthesis in the equation, although it can result in duplicated representation. Combinatorial analysis still reveals that the task is feasible.

Comment: I have a _feeling_ that placing 6! number concatenated with 4^5 operators in this order would not handle cases with parenthesis -- as that order only produces left or right-associative expressions. I don't think one can evaluate (1+2)/(3+4) with 'N N N N op op op'.

Comment: It will handle these cases with parenthesis. Forget about notation, focus on the order of operations only. You can express everything with this notation (if not, please give counterexample).

Comment: The simplest counterexample I can think of is (1-3)-7, which can't be calculated by permuting 1,3,7 and followed by '--'.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark - I stand corrected. Aki- Why not 1 - 3 - 7?

Comment: I may not understand you guys here. I do not recommend postfix expression. What I recommend is simply list of numbers and list of operations to be applied. That solves most, but the tricks like '(a+b)/(c+d)'. Since it requires 2 places in memory to store.

Answer (score 7):

A working solution in c++11 below.

The basic idea is to use a stack-based evaluation (see [RPN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_polish_notation)) and convert the viable solutions to [infix notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infix_notation) for display purposes only.

If we have `N` input digits, we'll use `(N-1)` operators, as each operator is binary.

First we create *valid permutations* of operands and operators (the `selector_` array). A valid permutation is one that can be evaluated without stack underflow and which ends with exactly one value (the result) on the stack. Thus `1 1 +` is valid, but `1 + 1` is not.

We test each such operand-operator permutation with every permutation of operands (the `values_` array) and every combination of operators (the `ops_` array). Matching results are pretty-printed.

Arguments are taken from command line as `[-s] <target> <digit>[ <digit>...]`. The `-s` switch prevents exhaustive search, only the first matching result is printed.

(use `./mathpuzzle 348 1 3 7 6 8 3` to get the answer for the original question)

This solution doesn't allow concatenating the input digits to form numbers. That could be added as an additional outer loop.

The working code can be downloaded from [here](https://bitbucket.org/mitchnull/samples/raw/tip/cpp/mathpuzzle.cpp). *(Note: I updated that code with support for concatenating input digits to form a solution)*

See code comments for additional explanation.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <stack>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>

namespace {

enum class Op {
    Add,
    Sub,
    Mul,
    Div,
};

const std::size_t NumOps = static_cast<std::size_t>(Op::Div) + 1;
const Op FirstOp = Op::Add;

using Number = int;

class Evaluator {
    std::vector<Number> values_; // stores our digits/number we can use
    std::vector<Op> ops_; // stores the operators
    std::vector<char> selector_; // used to select digit (0) or operator (1) when evaluating. should be std::vector<bool>, but that's broken

    template <typename T>
    using Stack = std::stack<T, std::vector<T>>;

    // checks if a given number/operator order can be evaluated or not
    bool isSelectorValid() const {
        int numValues = 0;
        for (auto s : selector_) {
            if (s) {
                if (--numValues <= 0) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            else {
                ++numValues;
            }
        }
        return (numValues == 1);
    }

    // evaluates the current values_ and ops_ based on selector_
    Number eval(Stack<Number> &stack) const {
        auto vi = values_.cbegin();
        auto oi = ops_.cbegin();
        for (auto s : selector_) {
            if (!s) {
                stack.push(*(vi++));
                continue;
            }
            Number top = stack.top();
            stack.pop();
            switch (*(oi++)) {
                case Op::Add:
                    stack.top() += top;
                    break;
                case Op::Sub:
                    stack.top() -= top;
                    break;
                case Op::Mul:
                    stack.top() *= top;
                    break;
                case Op::Div:
                    if (top == 0) {
                        return std::numeric_limits<Number>::max();
                    }
                    Number res = stack.top() / top;
                    if (res * top != stack.top()) {
                        return std::numeric_limits<Number>::max();
                    }
                    stack.top() = res;
                    break;
            }
        }
        Number res = stack.top();
        stack.pop();
        return res;
    }

    bool nextValuesPermutation() {
        return std::next_permutation(values_.begin(), values_.end());
    }

    bool nextOps() {
        for (auto i = ops_.rbegin(), end = ops_.rend(); i != end; ++i) {
            std::size_t next = static_cast<std::size_t>(*i) + 1;
            if (next < NumOps) {
                *i = static_cast<Op>(next);
                return true;
            }
            *i = FirstOp;
        }
        return false;
    }

    bool nextSelectorPermutation() {
        // the start permutation is always valid
        do {
            if (!std::next_permutation(selector_.begin(), selector_.end())) {
                return false;
            }
        } while (!isSelectorValid());
        return true;
    }

    static std::string buildExpr(const std::string& left, char op, const std::string &right) {
        return std::string("(") + left + ' ' + op + ' ' + right + ')';
    }

    std::string toString() const {
        Stack<std::string> stack;
        auto vi = values_.cbegin();
        auto oi = ops_.cbegin();
        for (auto s : selector_) {
            if (!s) {
                stack.push(std::to_string(*(vi++)));
                continue;
            }
            std::string top = stack.top();
            stack.pop();
            switch (*(oi++)) {
                case Op::Add:
                    stack.top() = buildExpr(stack.top(), '+', top);
                    break;
                case Op::Sub:
                    stack.top() = buildExpr(stack.top(), '-', top);
                    break;
                case Op::Mul:
                    stack.top() = buildExpr(stack.top(), '*', top);
                    break;
                case Op::Div:
                    stack.top() = buildExpr(stack.top(), '/', top);
                    break;
            }
        }
        return stack.top();
    }

public:
    Evaluator(const std::vector<Number>& values) :
            values_(values),
            ops_(values.size() - 1, FirstOp),
            selector_(2 * values.size() - 1, 0) {
        std::fill(selector_.begin() + values_.size(), selector_.end(), 1);
        std::sort(values_.begin(), values_.end());
    }

    // check for solutions
    // 1) we create valid permutations of our selector_ array (eg: "1 1 + 1 +",
    //    "1 1 1 + +", but skip "1 + 1 1 +" as that cannot be evaluated
    // 2) for each evaluation order, we permutate our values
    // 3) for each value permutation we check with each combination of
    //    operators
    // 
    // In the first version I used a local stack in eval() (see toString()) but
    // it turned out to be a performance bottleneck, so now I use a cached
    // stack. Reusing the stack gives an order of magnitude speed-up (from
    // 4.3sec to 0.7sec) due to avoiding repeated allocations.  Using
    // std::vector as a backing store also gives a slight performance boost
    // over the default std::deque.
    std::size_t check(Number target, bool singleResult = false) {
        Stack<Number> stack;

        std::size_t res = 0;
        do {
            do {
                do {
                    Number value = eval(stack);
                    if (value == target) {
                        ++res;
                        std::cout << target << " = " << toString() << "\n";
                        if (singleResult) {
                            return res;
                        }
                    }
                } while (nextOps());
            } while (nextValuesPermutation());
        } while (nextSelectorPermutation());
        return res;
    }
};

} // namespace

int main(int argc, const char **argv) {
    int i = 1;
    bool singleResult = false;
    if (argc > 1 && std::string("-s") == argv[1]) {
        singleResult = true;
        ++i;
    }
    if (argc < i + 2) {
        std::cerr << argv[0] << " [-s] <target> <digit>[ <digit>]...\n";
        std::exit(1);
    }
    Number target = std::stoi(argv[i]);
    std::vector<Number> values;
    while (++i <  argc) {
        values.push_back(std::stoi(argv[i]));
    }
    Evaluator evaluator{values};
    std::size_t res = evaluator.check(target, singleResult);
    if (!singleResult) {
        std::cout << "Number of solutions: " << res << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Input is obviously a set of digits and operators: D={1,3,3,6,7,8,3} and Op={+,-,*,/}. The most straight forward algorithm would be a [brute force](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brute-force_search) solver, which [enumerates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enumeration#Enumeration_in_computability_theory) all possible combinations of these sets. Where the elements of set Op can be used as often as wanted, but elements from set D are used exactly once. Pseudo code:

```
D={1,3,3,6,7,8,3}
Op={+,-,*,/}
Solution=348
for each permutation D_ of D:
   for each binary tree T with D_ as its leafs:
       for each sequence of operators Op_ from Op with length |D_|-1:
           label each inner tree node with operators from Op_
           result = compute T using infix traversal
           if result==Solution
              return T
return nil
```

Other than that: read jedrus07's and HPM's answers.

Answer (score 1):

By far the easiest approach is to intelligently brute force it. There is only a finite amount of expressions you can build out of 6 numbers and 4 operators, simply go through all of them.

How many? Since you don't have to use all numbers and may use the same operator multiple times, This problem is equivalent to "how many labeled strictly binary trees (aka full binary trees) can you make with at most 6 leaves, and four possible labels for each non-leaf node?".

The amount of full binary trees with n leaves is equal to catalan(n-1). You can see this as follows:

Every full binary tree with n leaves has n-1 internal nodes and corresponds to a non-full binary tree with n-1 nodes in a unique way (just delete all the leaves from the full one to get it). There happen to be catalan(n) possible binary trees with n nodes, so we can say that a strictly binary tree with n leaves has catalan(n-1) possible different structures.

There are 4 possible operators for each non-leaf node: 4^(n-1) possibilities
The leaves can be numbered in n! * (6 choose (n-1)) different ways. (Divide this by k! for each number that occurs k times, or just make sure all numbers are different)

So for 6 different numbers and 4 possible operators you get Sum(n=1...6) [ Catalan(n-1) * 6!/(6-n)! * 4^(n-1) ] possible expressions for a total of 33,665,406. Not a lot.

How do you enumerate these trees?

Given a collection of all trees with n-1 or less nodes, you can create all trees with n nodes by systematically pairing all of the n-1 trees with the empty tree, all n-2 trees with the 1 node tree, all n-3 trees with all 2 node tree etc. and using them as the left and right sub trees of a newly formed tree.

So starting with an empty set you first generate the tree that has just a root node, then from a new root you can use that either as a left or right sub tree which yields the two trees that look like this: / and . And so on.

You can turn them into a set of expressions on the fly (just loop over the operators and numbers) and evaluate them as you go until one yields the target number.

Answer (score 1):

I've written my own countdown solver, in Python.

Here's the code; it is also available on [GitHub](https://github.com/Pulsar1977/countdown_solver):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
from itertools import combinations, product, zip_longest
from functools import lru_cache

assert sys.version_info >= (3, 6)


class Solutions:

    def __init__(self, numbers):
        self.all_numbers = numbers
        self.size = len(numbers)
        self.all_groups = self.unique_groups()

    def unique_groups(self):
        all_groups = {}
        all_numbers, size = self.all_numbers, self.size
        for m in range(1, size+1):
            for numbers in combinations(all_numbers, m):
                if numbers in all_groups:
                    continue
                all_groups[numbers] = Group(numbers, all_groups)
        return all_groups

    def walk(self):
        for group in self.all_groups.values():
            yield from group.calculations


class Group:

    def __init__(self, numbers, all_groups):
        self.numbers = numbers
        self.size = len(numbers)
        self.partitions = list(self.partition_into_unique_pairs(all_groups))
        self.calculations = list(self.perform_calculations())

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.numbers)

    def partition_into_unique_pairs(self, all_groups):
        # The pairs are unordered: a pair (a, b) is equivalent to (b, a).
        # Therefore, for pairs of equal length only half of all combinations
        # need to be generated to obtain all pairs; this is set by the limit.
        if self.size == 1:
            return
        numbers, size = self.numbers, self.size
        limits = (self.halfbinom(size, size//2), )
        unique_numbers = set()
        for m, limit in zip_longest(range((size+1)//2, size), limits):
            for numbers1, numbers2 in self.paired_combinations(numbers, m, limit):
                if numbers1 in unique_numbers:
                    continue
                unique_numbers.add(numbers1)
                group1, group2 = all_groups[numbers1], all_groups[numbers2]
                yield (group1, group2)

    def perform_calculations(self):
        if self.size == 1:
            yield Calculation.singleton(self.numbers[0])
            return
        for group1, group2 in self.partitions:
            for calc1, calc2 in product(group1.calculations, group2.calculations):
                yield from Calculation.generate(calc1, calc2)

    @classmethod
    def paired_combinations(cls, numbers, m, limit):
        for cnt, numbers1 in enumerate(combinations(numbers, m), 1):
            numbers2 = tuple(cls.filtering(numbers, numbers1))
            yield (numbers1, numbers2)
            if cnt == limit:
                return

    @staticmethod
    def filtering(iterable, elements):
        # filter elements out of an iterable, return the remaining elements
        elems = iter(elements)
        k = next(elems, None)
        for n in iterable:
            if n == k:
                k = next(elems, None)
            else:
                yield n

    @staticmethod
    @lru_cache()
    def halfbinom(n, k):
        if n % 2 == 1:
            return None
        prod = 1
        for m, l in zip(reversed(range(n+1-k, n+1)), range(1, k+1)):
            prod = (prod*m)//l
        return prod//2


class Calculation:

    def __init__(self, expression, result, is_singleton=False):
        self.expr = expression
        self.result = result
        self.is_singleton = is_singleton

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.expr

    @classmethod
    def singleton(cls, n):
        return cls(f"{n}", n, is_singleton=True)

    @classmethod
    def generate(cls, calca, calcb):
        if calca.result < calcb.result:
            calca, calcb = calcb, calca
        for result, op in cls.operations(calca.result, calcb.result):
            expr1 = f"{calca.expr}" if calca.is_singleton else f"({calca.expr})"
            expr2 = f"{calcb.expr}" if calcb.is_singleton else f"({calcb.expr})"
            yield cls(f"{expr1} {op} {expr2}", result)

    @staticmethod
    def operations(x, y):
        yield (x + y, '+')
        if x > y:                     # exclude non-positive results
            yield (x - y, '-')
        if y > 1 and x > 1:           # exclude trivial results
            yield (x * y, 'x')
        if y > 1 and x % y == 0:      # exclude trivial and non-integer results
            yield (x // y, '/')


def countdown_solver():
    # input: target and numbers. If you want to play with more or less than
    # 6 numbers, use the second version of 'unsorted_numbers'.
    try:
        target = int(sys.argv[1])
        unsorted_numbers = (int(sys.argv[n+2]) for n in range(6))  # for 6 numbers
#        unsorted_numbers = (int(n) for n in sys.argv[2:])         # for any numbers
        numbers = tuple(sorted(unsorted_numbers, reverse=True))
    except (IndexError, ValueError):
        print("You must provide a target and numbers!")
        return

    solutions = Solutions(numbers)
    smallest_difference = target
    bestresults = []
    for calculation in solutions.walk():
        diff = abs(calculation.result - target)
        if diff <= smallest_difference:
            if diff < smallest_difference:
                bestresults = [calculation]
                smallest_difference = diff
            else:
                bestresults.append(calculation)
    output(target, smallest_difference, bestresults)


def output(target, diff, results):
    print(f"\nThe closest results differ from {target} by {diff}. They are:\n")
    for calculation in results:
        print(f"{calculation.result} = {calculation.expr}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
countdown_solver()
```

The algorithm works as follows:

1. The numbers are put into a tuple of length 6 in descending order. Then, all unique subgroups of lengths 1 to 6 are created, the smallest groups first.

   Example: (75, 50, 5, 9, 1, 1) -> {(75), (50), (9), (5), (1), (75, 50), (75, 9), (75, 5), ..., (75, 50, 9, 5, 1, 1)}.
2. Next, the groups are organised into a hierarchical tree: every group is partitioned into all unique unordered pairs of its non-empty subgroups.

   Example: (9, 5, 1, 1) -> [(9, 5, 1) + (1), (9, 1, 1) + (5), (5, 1, 1) + (9), (9, 5) + (1, 1), (9, 1) + (5, 1)].
3. Within each group of numbers, the calculations are performed and the results are stored. For groups of length 1, the result is simply the number itself. For larger groups, the calculations are carried out on every pair of subgroups: in each pair, all results of the first subgroup are combined with all results of the second subgroup using +, -, x and /, and the valid outcomes are stored.

   Example: (75, 5) consists of the pair ((75), (5)). The result of (75) is 75; the result of (5) is 5; the results of (75, 5) are [75+5=80, 75-5=70, 75*5=375, 75/5=15].
4. In this manner, all results are generated, from the smallest groups to the largest. Finally, the algorithm iterates through all results and selects the ones that are the closest match to the target number.

For a group of m numbers, the maximum number of arithmetic computations is

```
comps[m] = 4*sum(binom(m, k)*comps[k]*comps[m-k]//(1 + (2*k)//m) for k in range(1, m//2+1))
```

For all groups of length 1 to 6, the maximum total number of computations is then

```
total = sum(binom(n, m)*comps[m] for m in range(1, n+1))
```

which is 1144386. In practice, it will be much less, because the algorithm reuses the results of duplicate groups, ignores trivial operations (adding 0, multiplying by 1, etc), and because the rules of the game dictate that intermediate results must be positive integers (which limits the use of the division operator).

Answer (score 0):

I think, you need to strictly define the problem first. What you are allowed to do and what you are not. You can start by making it simple and only allowing multiplication, division, substraction and addition.

Now you know your problem space- set of inputs, set of available operations and desired input. If you have only 4 operations and x inputs, the number of combinations is less than:

The number of order in which you can carry out operations (x!) times the possible choices of operations on every step: 4^x. As you can see for 6 numbers it gives reasonable 2949120 operations. This means that this may be your limit for brute force algorithm.

Once you have brute force and you know it works, you can start improving your algorithm with some sort of [A* algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%2a_search_algorithm) which would require you to define heuristic functions.

In my opinion the best way to think about it is as the search problem. The main difficulty will be finding good heuristics, or ways to reduce your problem space (if you have numbers that do not add up to the answer, you will need at least one multiplication etc.). Start small, build on that and ask follow up questions once you have some code.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a slightly simpler version:

1. for every combination of 2 (distinct) elements from the list and combine them using +,-,*,/ (note that since a>b then only a-b is needed and only a/b if a%b=0)
2. if combination is target then record solution
3. recursively call on the reduced lists

```
import sys

def driver():
    try:
        target = int(sys.argv[1])
        nums = list((int(sys.argv[i+2]) for i in range(6)))
    except (IndexError, ValueError):
        print("Provide a list of 7 numbers")
        return
    solutions = list()
    solve(target, nums, list(), solutions)
    unique = set()
    final = list()
    for s in solutions:
        a = '-'.join(sorted(s))
        if not a in unique:
            unique.add(a)
            final.append(s)
    for s in final:     #print them out
        print(s)

def solve(target, nums, path, solutions):
    if len(nums) == 1:
        return
    distinct = sorted(list(set(nums)), reverse = True)
    rem1 = list(distinct)
    for n1 in distinct: #reduce list by combining a pair
        rem1.remove(n1)
        for n2 in rem1:
            rem2 = list(nums)       # in case of duplicates we need to start with full list and take out the n1,n2 pair of elements
            rem2.remove(n1)
            rem2.remove(n2)
            combine(target, solutions, path, rem2, n1, n2, '+')
            combine(target, solutions, path, rem2, n1, n2, '-')
            if n2 > 1:
                combine(target, solutions, path, rem2, n1, n2, '*')
                if not n1 % n2:
                    combine(target, solutions, path, rem2, n1, n2, '//')

def combine(target, solutions, path, rem2, n1, n2, symb):
    lst = list(rem2)
    ans = eval("{0}{2}{1}".format(n1, n2, symb))
    newpath = path + ["{0}{3}{1}={2}".format(n1, n2, ans, symb[0])]
    if ans == target:
        solutions += [newpath]
    else:
        lst.append(ans)
        solve(target, lst, newpath, solutions)
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    driver()
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a terminal application to do this:
https://github.com/pg328/CountdownNumbersGame/tree/main

Inside, I've included an illustration of the calculation of the size of the solution space (it's n*((n-1)!^2)*(2^n-1), so: n=6 -> 2,764,800. I know, gross), and more importantly why that is. My implementation is there if you care to check it out, but in case you don't I'll explain here.

Essentially, at worst it is brute force because as far as I know it's impossible to determine whether any specific branch will result in a valid answer without explicitly checking. Having said that, the **average case** is some fraction of that; it's {that number} divided by the number of valid solutions (I tend to see around 1000 on my program, where 10 or so are unique and the rest are permutations fo those 10). If I handwaved a number, I'd say roughly 2,765 branches to check which takes like *no time*. (Yes, even in Python.)

TL;DR: Even though the solution space is huge and it takes a couple million operations to find *all solutions*, only one answer is needed. Best route is brute force til you find one and spit it out.