# Writing an algorithm to decide whether a target number can be reached with a set of other numbers and specific operators?

Tags: algorithm, math

I'm trying to learn more about algorithm design, and I've set myself the challenge of creating a simple game that presents users with an array of numbers, a target number, and a range of operators (plus, minus, multiply, divide, perhaps square root and such later). What I need to do is decide whether or not it's possible to make that target number using the available numbers in the array.

I'm a little stumped on where to begin with this. In different rounds of the game, different operators may be available, such as `+, -, *, and /`, `+ and -`, only `+ and *`, or all except `+`, etc.

Am I right in saying that I would effectively need a separate algorithm for each combination of operators (however many there are, 20 or whatever)? And if so, will I then need to iterate through each number in the grid, performing each available operator on each other number in the array? That seems overly messy, but I'm not really sure what other options there are. This option also doesn't follow any specific path through multiple operations (for instance if I wanted to make `7`, I may do `12 + 5 - 10` if those were the only numbers available to me in the array).

Could anyone give me some pointers on where to begin with this kind of problem?

Comment: You might want to start by reading references to the "four fours" problem (e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_fours) or "countdown" problems (e.g. http://eprints.nottingham.ac.uk/226/1/countdown.pdf)

Comment: Maybe my comment will be off the topic, but I believe you are looking to the problem from the wrong perspective. In your code, you already have the target number. What you'll have to do is create a function that outputs the level operators and the array of input numbers. Leave the challenge to the players. Unless one of the players is the AI of your game.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15293232/how-to-design-an-algorithm-to-calculate-countdown-style-maths-number-puzzle/15293397#15293397

Comment: @AlexFilipovici So you're suggesting that when I generate the array, I definitively generate at least one correct solution in it at that point in time? If so, how do I stop the user from, say, using one of the necessary numbers in an incorrect way, and thus coming into a no-win situation in that way?

Comment: Maybe you should consider limiting also the number of operator usages.

Comment: Is it compulsory to use each number atleast once ?

Comment: @bjskishore123 Not at all, I'm actually thinking there'd be an array of perhaps 50 or so numbers, and once one is used, it can't be used again.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are facing a more generalized problem of the [Partition Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem), which is [NP-Complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-complete).

The Partition Problem is: Given `n` numbers, split them into two (distinct) groups `A` and `B` such that `sum(A) = sum(B)`. Now, it is easy to see that if you have a problem with +,- operators and target number 0 - this is basically the same problem, and there is an immidiate reduction from Partition Problem to your problem.

From this we can conclude your problem is [NP-Hard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-hard) as well, and **there is no known polynomial solution for your problem**.

Alternatives are:

1. [Brute Force](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brute-force_search) (As suggested by @Sayakiss)
2. Depending on the operators - you might be able to use some [branch and bound](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_and_bound) techniques.
3. [For Partition Problem there is pseudo-polynomial Dynamic Programming solution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem#The_pseudo-polynomial_algorithm), that might be utilized in here as well, at least for some of the cases.

Sorry if it's bad news -but at least you won't be looking for something that (most computer scientists believe) is not there

Comment: *something that is not there* ... yet :-)

Comment: @ring0 I suppose I'd better go create it then, if it's not there yet. That's why I'm learning this stuff, I suppose. :)

Comment: @lukech This is the [P vs NP Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P_versus_NP_problem), which is still open (and got 1,000,000$ bounty on it). Creating such an algorithm (in polynomial time) will prove P=NP. Most researchers believe however that P!=NP, so if this is the case - such algorithm does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

1. Enumerate all possible expressions. For numbers 1,2,3,and operator + and - ,you can get:1+2+3,1+2-3,1-2+3,1-2-3.
2. Evaluate all possible expressions.

Comment: 2+3-1 is missing. I mean, not just operator permuations, need to consider number ordering possibilities as well.

Comment: @bjskishore123 then just consider the permutation of numbers. You can use some heuristic method to prune the search.

Comment: @Sayakiss Enumerating the expressions is the part I'm having trouble with, and why I asked the question in the first place really. Telling me to just "do it" isn't very helpful. Could you explain roughly how I might go about creating a list of all possible expressions, particularly since they can be of varying lengths?

Comment: @lukech How do you generate a permutation? If you can do this ,then it's the similar idea to that problem; If you can't, search it in google and you will get massive information about that.

Comment: @Sayakiss I'm not sure what you mean by generating a permutation.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a Java [solution](http://www.programcreek.com/2016/04/get-target-using-number-list-and-arithmetic-operations-google/) from programcreek.

```
public static boolean isReachable(ArrayList<Integer> list, int target) {
    if (list == null || list.size() == 0)
        return false;

    int i = 0;
    int j = list.size() - 1;

    ArrayList<Integer> results = getResults(list, i, j, target);

    for (int num : results) {
        if (num == target) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

public static ArrayList<Integer> getResults(ArrayList<Integer> list,
        int left, int right, int target) {
    ArrayList<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    if (left > right) {
        return result;
    } else if (left == right) {
        result.add(list.get(left));
        return result;
    }

    for (int i = left; i < right; i++) {

        ArrayList<Integer> result1 = getResults(list, left, i, target);
        ArrayList<Integer> result2 = getResults(list, i + 1, right, target);

        for (int x : result1) {
            for (int y : result2) {
                result.add(x + y);
                result.add(x - y);
                result.add(x * y);
                if (y != 0)
                    result.add(x / y);
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```