# How to print the calculated process of a game like 24point?

Tags: algorithm

Here's the problem:
Given 4 numbers, I need to give a calculated process which results 24. All the operations I can use are addition, subtraction, multiplication, division. How to print the calculated process?
Ex:
Input: 4,7,8,8
Output: (7-(8/8))*4=24.

Comment: If you know how to find the correct operations, printing them is straightforward. Are you sure you are asking the right question?

Comment: read this will help you a lot . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16564543/writing-an-algorithm-to-decide-whether-a-target-number-can-be-reached-with-a-set/16565752#16565752

Answer (score 1):

(The following is an expansion on an idea suggested by Sayakiss)

One option would be enumerating all possible combinations of numbers and arithmetic operations performed on them.

If you have 4 numbers, there are only 24 different ways to write them in a list (the following example is for numbers 4, 7, 8, 9 - i changed the last number in your example to make them all different):

```
4 7 8 9
4 7 9 8
4 8 7 9
4 8 9 7
...
9 8 7 4
```

If some numbers are identical, some of the above lists will appear twice (not a problem).

For each of the above orderings, there are 64 different ways to insert an arithmetic operation between the numbers:

```
4+7+8+9
4+7+8-9
4+7+8*9
4+7+8/9
4+7-8+9
...
4/7/8/9
```

For each of the above sequences, there are 5 ways to place parentheses:

```
((4-7)-8)-9
(4-7)-(8-9)
(4-(7-8))-9
4-((7-8)-9)
4-(7-(8-9))
```

When you combine all 3 "aspects" mentioned above, you get 24 * 64 * 5 = 7680 expressions; evaluate each one and check whether its value is 24 (or whatever number you need it to be).

It may be convenient to generate the expressions in a tree form, to simplify evaluation (this depends on the programming language you want to use; e.g. in C/C++ there is no [eval function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eval)) . For example, the expression `4*((7-8)+9)` may be represented by the following tree:

```
  *
 / \
4   +
   / \
  -   9
 / \
7   8
```

Some notes:

- You may want to tweak the choice of arithmetic operations to allow for expressions like `47+88` - not sure whether the rules of your game permit that.
- Many of the evaluated expressions may be annoyingly verbose, like `((4+7)+8)+8` and `4+(7+(8+8))` (which are also examined twice, with the order of the 8's switched); you could prevent that by inserting some dedicated checks into your algorithm.