# Brute force search algorithm

Tags: python, r, algorithm, math

Problem statement as follows:

*Input 1*: a list of distinct numbers, `l1`
*Input 2*: a single number, `t`

*Output*: all the combinations of `l1` that can yield `t` using `+`, `-`, `*` or `"/"` .

We have to arrive at a single result using arithmetic operations on numbers given, e.g.:

```
l <- c(2,3,4,5)
t <- 6
```

Output should come as:

```
6=((2+3)-(4-5))
6=((2+3)-(4-5))
6=((2+3)+(5-4))
6=(((2+3)-4)+5)
6=(((2+3)+5)-4)
6=((2+3)+(5-4))
6=(((2+3)-4)+5)
6=(((2+3)+5)-4)
6=((2*3)*(5-4))
6=((2*3)/(5-4))
6=((5-4)*(2*3))
6=((2/3)*(4+5))
```

I don't know how I can code this, it would be very helpful if I can get some reference.

*Ref:* [Wikipedia Numbers_round](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Countdown_(game_show)#Numbers_round)

Comment: What did you try so far? It will be better to explain the problem you are trying to solve with expected results. Not many ppl will want to read code to understand the question. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Number of possibilities: `n<- length(l); factorial(n)*4^n `. this will be a hassle to compute with not so large `l`

Comment: This repo might be useful: https://github.com/rvedotrc/numbers , solution is using C.

Comment: Another useful post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15293232/how-to-design-an-algorithm-to-calculate-countdown-style-maths-number-puzzle

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a coding or tutorial service.